# Hover Effect Caption with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div inside a list item with the display set to none. I want it to fade in when that list item is hovered over. I have been at this for about an hour trying various tutorials but I just can't get it to work...

```
<li data-tags="Websites" class="boxgrid captionfull">
    <img src="resources/Portfolio/Thumbs/ChugBeersWebsite.jpg" width="200" />
    <div class="boxcaption">
        <h3>Chug Beers Site</h3>
        <p><a href="http://www.chugbeers.com">Visit Site</a></p>
    </div>
</li>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(function(){
       $('.captionfull').hover(function(){  
            $(".boxcaption").fadeIn('slow');  
        }, function() {  
            $(".boxcaption").fadeOut('slow');  
        });  
    })
});  
</script>
```

I believe the following script is conflicting it somehow. I am using a filterable portfolio plugin, and I don't know enough jquery to want to mess with it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var items = $('#stage li'),
    itemsByTags = {};

// Looping though all the li items:

items.each(function(i){
    var elem = $(this),
        tags = elem.data('tags').split(',');

    // Adding a data-id attribute. Required by the Quicksand plugin:
    elem.attr('data-id',i);

    $.each(tags,function(key,value){

        // Removing extra whitespace:
        value = $.trim(value);

        if(!(value in itemsByTags)){
            // Create an empty array to hold this item:
            itemsByTags[value] = [];
        }

        // Each item is added to one array per tag:
        itemsByTags[value].push(elem);
    });

});

// Creating the "Everything" option in the menu:
createList('Everything',items);

// Looping though the arrays in itemsByTags:
$.each(itemsByTags,function(k,v){
    createList(k,v);
});

$('#filter a').live('click',function(e){
    var link = $(this);

    link.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    // Using the Quicksand plugin to animate the li items.
    // It uses data('list') defined by our createList function:

    $('#stage').quicksand(link.data('list').find('li'));
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('#filter a:first').click();

function createList(text,items){

    // This is a helper function that takes the
    // text of a menu button and array of li items

    // Creating an empty unordered list:
    var ul = $('<ul>',{'class':'hidden'});

    $.each(items,function(){
        // Creating a copy of each li item
        // and adding it to the list:

        $(this).clone().appendTo(ul);
    });

    ul.appendTo('#container');

    // Creating a menu item. The unordered list is added
    // as a data parameter (available via .data('list'):

    var a = $('<a>',{
        html: text,
        href:'#',
        data: {list:ul}
    }).appendTo('#filter');
}
});

#container{
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
width: 960px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0px;
}

#container li{
float: left;
height: 229px;
list-style: none outside none;
margin: 20px;
position: relative;
width: 200px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
border-radius: 7px;
overflow:hidden;
display:block;      
}
#container li img{
border-radius:7px;
position: absolute;  
}
#container ul{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
#container ul.hidden{
display:none;
} 
.boxcaption{
text-align: center;
float: left;
position: absolute;
height: 100px;
width: 190px;
color: #FFF;
display: none;
bottom: 0;
border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-left: 5px;
background-image: url(../resources/blackbg.png);
background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like undefined mentioned, you might need to use the jQuery document ready handler. And since you're already using jQuery, might as well use the [fadeToggle](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) method for less code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.captionfull').hover(function(){
    $(".boxcaption", this).fadeToggle('slow');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.captionfull').hover(function(){  
        $(this).children('.boxcaption').fadeIn('slow');  
    }, function() {  
        $(this).children('.boxcaption').fadeOut('slow');  
    }).children('.boxcaption').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<ul>
<li data-tags="Websites" class="boxgrid captionfull" style="border:1px solid #CCC;width:400px;">
    <img src="http://www.chugbeers.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/41Y82evIPSL-195x300.jpeg" width="200" />
    <div class="boxcaption" style="display:;">
        <h3>Chug Beers Site</h3>
        <p><a href="http://www.chugbeers.com">Visit Site</a></p>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.captionfull').hover(function(e){
        $(".boxcaption", this).animate({opacity:'1'},{queue:false,duration:1000});
    }, function(f) {
        $(".boxcaption", this).animate({opacity:'0'},{queue:false,duration:1000});
    });
</script>
```

I find that using animate gives you more control. Set queue to true if you want the fade to execute on every hover, false if you don't care.

Comment: I turned off that other script just to try your approach and this did not work.

Comment: That's weird: here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nebulousal/zwuZm/

maybe you need to give us more code to work with?

Comment: You have all the code. I've added the css to the description

Comment: So, what happens when you use the animate method? Can you post it to jsFiddle.net? Because, the code I'm testing seems to be working fine... I updated it slightly to provide for hiding the caption onload: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/nebulousal/zwuZm/1/)

Comment: Got it! The issue is in your css: for .boxcaption, use opacity: 0 instead of display:none;. In ie, you would need to do opacity(0);

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/G5Ddc/3/ I get the same result even with the opacity change...

Comment: Couple things: 1- You have to add jQuery in jsFiddle (on the left- dropdown). 2- The javascript should have the <script> tags removed. Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/nebulousal/zwuZm/2/

Comment: Alright, I can see how it works there, and now I literally copied and pasted the code into mine, and it's still not working... that is the only script in the document now too.

Comment: Ok- here it is in ALL HTML with the jquery Lib added in etc: http://jsfiddle.net/nebulousal/zwuZm/3/ -AND- Just in case, here it is on a dev server: http://web2.nebdev.net/tasks/sandbox/t.html . I tested it in chrome, ff and safari on os x and it works great.

Comment: PS- IE 8 and IE 9 don't seem to work. Are you using one of these browsers?

Comment: I'm crashin: let me know what happens. GL

Comment: This worked now, but once again when I combine it with the script above something is conflicting and I just don't know what.

Comment: Can you post EXACTLY what you have?